# 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED - POST in EDIT

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, http-status-code-405

Im new to coding Im working in a project (CRUD - asp.net).
My setup was SQL - API - MVC

So this is what happened:
*CRUD is working when I tried it in localhost, but upon deploying it in web app service, I got a problem with EDIT mode only.*

GET is working (it was able to retrieve the data)
POST isn't (when im saving it error is found)

Upon checking the debug mode status code of POST in EDIT says 405 Method not Allowed

My question is why my CREATE functionality works with get and post but in EDIT im having an issue. What makes the restriction.

Note: **CREATE and DELETE are workkng**.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cuz your action HttpMethod attribute is not matching the request http method.

for example if this is your action:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> edit()
{
}
```

then your request must use http Put method to call this action.

Comment: Hello sorry i got confused. Please bear with me im from a non tech background new to this. I have an API (which states all the httpget httppost, httpput and httpdelete) now using MVC Im calling this API. So now we are in the MVC, when CREATE is trigger it has httpget and httppost ryt? Its working. Now in EDIT it has httpget and httppost too, so do you mean httppost of EDIT should be httpput? Thank you

Comment: Well, the restfull principle says that, you should use httpGet for api's that return data, HttpPost for api's that insert data, HttpPut for api's that edit data, and HttpDelete for api's that delete data. are you using postman to send request to your api web application?